# umbrella header 'realm.h' not found after installing xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode10

After updating to xcode 10, am getting the below error when I compile:

"umbrella header 'realm.h' not found"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It could be realm version,

Comment: Can you provide the entire error what you are getting ?

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem by switching build system:

1. Open `File -> Xcode Workspace Settings`
2. Switch Build System to "Legacy Build System".